# C# regex to validate "realistic" IP values

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Regex that somewhat validates if a value has one of the following characteristics:

```
123-29-123-123.subdomain.zomg.com:8085
123.12.34.56:420
```

Unfortunately, I'm terrible at Regex, C#, google searches, and the differences between proper nouns and regular ones.

It can be a lose approximation, in fact I would go with anything that has a : colon separator with a port after it.

Comment: Your first example is really a hostname with a port, not an IP address with a port. Do you want to validate just IP addresses, or addresses and hostnames?

Answer (score 2):

Will this work?

```
^(?<Host>[^:]+)(?::(?<Port>\d+))?$
```

This gives me:

```
Host = 123-29-123-123.subdomain.zomg.com
Port = 8085
```

and

```
Host = 123.12.34.56:420
Port = 420
```

Comment: Yeah, but at that point, the port format fails 100% of the time anyways.

Comment: I think this is a bit too loose. It matches things like `?*&%#.?*&%#.?*&%#.?*&%#.?*&%#.:4` with `?*&%#.?*&%#.?*&%#.?*&%#.?*&%#.` as the host. Is that a valid host name?

Comment: @Frustrated:  No, it isn't. Regexes are not parsers.  Don't use regexes for parsing.  Use regexes for pattern matching.  The only way to tell if it is a valid host name is to try to use it as a host name.  What's the regex to tell if a host is online?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the simplest regex would probably be:

`(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(:\d+)?`

***But***... this would allow things like `999.999.999` which is not a *valid* (the format is valid, but not the values) IP address.

If you want to validate each block, best to do that outside a regex.

Comment: You could use `[01]?\d{1,2}|2[01234]\d|25[012345]` instead of `\d{1,3}` to match only numbers from 0 to 255.

Answer (score 0):

One can negate a match using what I call the Match Invalidator (?! ) (Match if Suffix is **absent**). (I wrote a blog article entited: [Regular Expression (Regex) Match Invalidator (?!) in .Net](http://www.omegacoder.com/?p=30) on it)

In (?! *Suffix*) If the suffix is *matched* then the match fails. I have taken into account the possibilities of 256-999 and 000 using (?! ). Here is the pattern, use IgnorePatternWhiteSpace because I have commented the pattern:

```
string pattern = @"
^(                      # Anchor to the beginning of the line
                        # Invalidations
  (?!25[6-9])              # If 256, 257...259 are found STOP
  (?!2[6-9]\d)             # If 260-299 stop
  (?![3-9]\d\d)            # if 300-999 stop
  (?!000)                  # No zeros
  (\d{1,3})             # Between 1-3 numbers
  (?:[.-]?)             # Match but don't capture a . or -
 ){4,6}                 # IPV4 IPV6
(?<Url>[A-Za-z.\d]*?)   # Subdomain is mostly text
(?::)
(?<Port>\d+)";
```

HTH

Comment: I think it is called negative lookahead (http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)